# Visual Studio Team Services - Archive Task wraps source in a folder

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have created a build definition as follows:

[image]

My Repository doesn't have any subfolders and its simple as this:
[image]

What I get after the build is slightly different than I would expect. It has an `s/` folder before the source, like this:

`s/
  node_modules
  .gitattributtes
  .gitignore
  index.html
  package.json`

#### How to ensure this `s/` folder is not automatically included in the archive?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need to uncheck the option of prefix root folder name to archive paths.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I feel weird about not paying attention to that checkbox. It worked!